# How do we change the page size of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969.aspx),

> In SQL Server, the page size is 8 KB. This means SQL Server databases
>   have 128 pages per megabyte.

**How do we change the page size, e.g. to 4 KB or 12 KB etc?**

Also, is it due to an "*innate* hardware restriction" that page sizes are chosen to be 8 KB?

Or is 8 KB simply an arbitrary good-enough number chosen based on heuristics for optimization of *majority* use cases?

Comment: 2) - **you don't** - it's a system-wide, hard-coded setting, no way to change it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot change it.

For reason of efficiency of addressing ([TLB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer)) and efficiency of IO (see [Reading From or Writing To Files Using a Scatter-Gather Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) the database page size must be some multiple of the OS page size, which is driven by the platform hardware architecture. x86 architecture has a 4k page size (see the sidebar on [x86 Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86), or refer to the [Intel Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/)), newer architectures offer large pages and SQL Server leverages them for memory allocations, see [SQL Server and Large Pages Explained](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/06/05/sql-server-and-large-pages-explained.aspx).

For reasons of database file portability the on-disk file format cannot be changed to accommodate modern CPU larger pages, it would  break the capability to read the database on an older hardware. And experience shows that the 1MB page is quite difficult to allocate soon after OS start up, due to physical RAM fragmentation (a processor page must map to a contiguous hardware page). And such a large page would not play well with WAL (See [ARIES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_Recovery_and_Isolation_Exploiting_Semantics)).

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server does not allow the page size to be changed - it is a fixed 8k in size with a fixed size header / data section.

Answer (score 2):

1) The 8KB page is just a bit of legacy. I don't think there's any "good" reason for a fixed 8KB page size limitation but changing it would likely require a big investment from Microsoft and possibly a difficult upgrade path for customers.

2) Can't be done. The option to change it would be a very nice feature and is perhaps a long overdue enhancement but not something we're likely to see for a few years at least.