# Size of Data Pages in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

Why Data Pages in SQL Server have exactly 8KB, not for example 16KB or 64KB? All databases are organized data in the same way?

Comment: By design. Sql Server architects (or maybe Sybase) decided that. Possible related: [How do we change the page size of SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067365/how-do-we-change-the-page-size-of-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

The 8K page size was introduced with the rewrite of the SQL Server storage engine in SQL Server 7.0.  Prior to that, the page size was only 2K.  Since the minimal IO transfer unit is a page, the chosen page size is a compromise between IOPS and latency for single-page IO as well as buffer memory management and storage management structures.

SQL Server also performs IO in multiples of 64K extents (8 contiguous pages) when it is advantageous to do so (e.g. read-ahead scans).  This allows more data to be transferred with fewer IOPS without resorting to a large page size to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you would need to ask the original designers, who would have been at Sybase (or even some pre-cursor to that).  That is, this decision was made in the 1990s or 1980s.

The page is sort-of the unit of I/O (I think SQL Server actually reads four pages at a time).  The optimal size would balance the *latency* of the I/O system against the *bandwidth*.  Latency is the delay inherent in communicating to a disk.  A major component for spinning disks is the movement of the read-head on the disk itself.  Bandwidth is how fast data is transferred.  These then need to be balanced against CPU speed.

In those days, latency and bandwidth were much lower than today.  8k was probably a reasonable value.  8k pages are baked solidly into SQL Server, so it would probably be quite hard to change.  Nowadays, disks are faster.  SSDs basically have minimal latency.  File systems have hardware-enabled caching, both for reading and writing.  It is not clear that 8k would be the optimal size for a newly-designed database.